# How to dynamically create one input with the value of another in AWS step function states?

Tags: java, aws-step-functions

I want to make the output of a state on the basis of input it received.

I have created a generic activity `CopyFileActivity` that copies a file from one S3 bucket to another. 
As a intial input it the name of external service, execute some other activities and then executes `CopyFileActivity` activity. 
I have a folder corresponding to each service. Is there a way to dynamically know the name of folder as an input of `CopyFileActivity`?

Intial input is as below:

```
{
    "service": "xyz"
}
```

My S3 folder structure is like `external-test-<service_name>`, for this particular case as `external-test-xyz`.

I want the input of `CopyFileActivity` activity as:

```
{
    "sourceBucket": "external-test-xyz",
    "destBucket": "internal-test-xyz"
}
```

NOTE - prefixes `external-test-` and `internal-test-` are fixed.

Various ways:

1. Changing the code of activity and create the `sourceBucket` and `destBucket` itself in activity instead of passing as input. But I want to make this activity generic, since It would be used in many other scenario.
2. Changing the initial input as:

   ```
   {
       "service": "xyz",
       "sourceBucket": "external-test-xyz",
       "destBucket": "internal-test-xyz"
   }
   ```

   This would work, but `sourceBucket` and `destBucket` are redundant params. It can also produce bug as someone gives might give bucket names.
3. A pass state where required params would be created

   ```
   {
         "Type": "Pass",
         "Parameters": {
           "service.$": "$.service",
           "sourceBucket.$": "external-test-", (something logic here)
           "destBucket.$": "internal-test-", (same logic here)
           "fileName": "fileName"
         },
         "Next": "CopyFileActivity"
   }
   ```

I tried doing things like `"sourceBucket.$": "external-test-" + "$.service"`, but not correct.

Is there any way to do this or can anyone please suggest any other approach to deal with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `States.Format` [intrinsic function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-intrinsic-functions.html#asl-intrsc-func-generic) in your `Pass` state to append the `$.service` input to the bucket prefixes:

```json
{
  "Type": "Pass",
  "Parameters": {
    "service.$": "$.service",
    "sourceBucket.$": "States.Format('external-test-{}', $.service)",
    "destBucket.$": "States.Format('internal-test-{}', $.service)",
    "fileName": "fileName"
  },
  "ResultPath": "$",
  "Next": "CopyFileActivity"
}
```

output:

```json
{
  "service": "xyz",
  "sourceBucket": "external-test-xyz",
  "destBucket": "internal-test-xyz",
  "fileName": "fileName"
}
```